# What does ">>>>" or "<<<<" mean or do in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have found this operator in a book about Node.js. I don't know what it does or mean. In the code below is more context for where I found this

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Pulser extends EventEmitter {
    start() {
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} >>>> pulse`);
            this.emit('pulse');
            console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} <<<< pulse`);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
module.exports = Pulser;
```

Comment: At first glance they look like bitwise operators.

Comment: There's no operator there, that's just part of the string. The only interpolated variable is `new Date().toISOString()`.

Comment: Its just a string, instead of the `"` you can use the ` to define a string witch can have the special `$` tags

Comment: It's just a log, nothing interpreted or executed at all.

Comment: It's not bitwise anyway as that only has three `>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_(Zero-fill_right_shift)

Comment: It's just a string ">>>>" - since it's not wrapped in a template literal `${}`

Comment: It does not mean anything. It is just a sequence of characters in a string. You can safely replace them with `abcd` and `efgh` and the code will continue to work (only the logged messages are a bit different than before).

Answer (score 2):

There's no operator there, that's just part of the string. The only interpolated variable is `new Date().toISOString()`. – CertainPerformance